# Unable to properly reference TextView from java within same activity

Tags: java, android

I am running a basic application that passes information between two screens, but I'm crashing as soon as I select to move to the second activity.

Commenting out blocks of code, I have narrowed the problem down to a NULL object.

---

> ***XML File "activity_two"***
>
> `<RelativeLayout 
>           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>           xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>           android:layout_width="match_parent"
>           android:layout_height="match_parent" 
>           android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
>           android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
>           android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>           android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>           tools:context="com.id11434343.exercise2.ActivityTwo">`
>
> `<TextView
>           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
>           android:text="@string/hintName"
>           android:id="@+id/textViewName"
>           android:layout_below="@+id/textViewHeader"
>           android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>`

---

> ***Java File "ActivityTwo"***
>
> `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
>       {
>           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>           Intent parentIntent = getIntent();
>           String name = parentIntent.getStringExtra(ActivityOne.NAME_MESSAGE);
>           TextView finalName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
>           finalName.setText(name);
>       }`

When I run `TextView finalName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);`, it passes a null reference. I have a similar line in the first activity, `EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);`, but experience no problem.

> ***Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:*** Attempt to invoke virtual method *'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)*' on a null object reference com.id11434343.exercise2.ActivityTwo.onCreate ActivityTwo.java:34)"

I receive this error, and have tried debug to get a closer look. My `EditText name = null`, however, the `R.id.editTextName = 2131558488`, which appears to be a valid ID, in line with the IDs from other elements. I have found a couple of similar questions, on here, but they previously appear to have come down to simple errors, such as using incorrect references, so I double checked my variables, and compared it directly to the working version, to ensure I was not missing something small.

Am I missing something here? I can't understand why I'm having troubles with a ViewText, where I didn't have any problems doing the same thing with an EditText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This passes null when you use a wrong layout in `setContentView()` means that the given id doesn't exist in the given layout.

Comment: Awesome. Spot on. I was following a guide, and must of missed the bit where they had me replace the setContentView, after initially removing it. Will update my question to show this, if others run into the same problem.

Comment: certainly. you got on it so quickly, I had to wait for a cool down :P